# Django slow query when ForeignKey null=True

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, foreign-keys

I set `null=True` on one of the `ForeignKey` fields in my Django model, and now when I query that model, it is about 10 times slower. (I'm using `select_related()`)

Looking at my Postgres logs before and after the change gives clues to the reason:

- **Before** setting `null=True`, the SQL that is generated is a single select statement with a couple of inner joins.
- **After** setting `null=True`, the SQL that is generated leaves out one of the joins and instead is followed by thousands of identical select statements.

So it's the classic **n+1** query issue, and [until this is fixed](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3665), how can I set `null=True` on a `ForeignKey` field without taking performance hits?

Comment: do you've bounded the `select_related` through the `depth` arg or a field name?

Comment: No bounds on it, would that help?

Comment: Maybe your breakdown isn't just for the `null=True`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this through a [raw query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/). Take a look to the query that is generated before putting `null=True` and execute it via a `raw` query instead of using 'top-level django ORM'. The breakdown is due the ORM don't the Postgres server, so you can avoid useless code generation running the SQL code directly.

Comment: This is a nice solution. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

From the official document, that is the limitation of the `select_related()` method, [here is the details](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related).

But you could have specified the related field in `select_relate()`, something like

```
modelA.objects.select_related('ModelAForeignKeyName__RelatedModelFeildName')
```